# WebAPI No action was found on the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I got an error - No action was found on the controller 'Action' that matches the request.

The url is `http://localhost:37331/api/action/FindByModule/1`.

The routing I used is

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Controller:

```
public class ActionController : ApiController
{
    private IActionRepository repository = null;

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("All")]
    public IEnumerable<JsonAction> All()
    {
        return from action in this.repository.Get()
               select new JsonAction
               {
                   ID = action.ID,
                   Text = action.Text.Trim(),
                   Description = action.Description.Trim(),
               };
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("FindByModule")]
    public IEnumerable<JsonAction> FindByModule(Int64 moduleId)
    {
        return from action in this.repository.FindByModule(moduleId)
               select new JsonAction
               {
                   ID = action.ID,
                   Text = action.Text.Trim(),
                   Description = action.Description.Trim(),
               };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This is because there is a parameter name mismatch. From your route the value **1** is assigned to parameter named `id` and your action is looking for parameter named `moduleId`.

First option is to change your route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{moduleId}",
    defaults: new { moduleId = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Second is to change your URL like this:

```
http://localhost:37331/api/action/FindByModule?moduleId=1
```

So the parameter name match.

Comment: Thank you @tpeczek, I didn't realize the parameter name must match the route template.

Comment: What if in one action i have moduleId, and in another captionId, how to pickup both without mismatch?

Comment: @evc You need separate rules for both actions. If they are in different controllers then you have tu put controller into route instead of placeholder. If they are in the same controller than you need to put those two actions names into separate rules. Also please remember to put the general route last.

Comment: Please confirm, if i have will have multiple rules in webapiconfig, they will all work, without problems? _i have multiple gets in 1 controller, their names are not same, and but params same_

Comment: @evc The simplest way to describe how routing egine works is to say that it goes through all the rules you have defined (in the order you have defined them) and uses the first one which is matching (this is why the most general rule should be last).

Comment: Here's something I don't understand. My only MapHttpRoute call doesn't specify any parameters, just "api/{controller}/{action}". But I can create controller actions that take a user (programmer) defined type as a parameter, and post JSON.stringified versions of that user defined type just fine. But if I try to create a controller action that takes, say, a single string parameter, when I try to post to that action it won't find it.

Comment: why it works only with findbymodule?moduleId=1? Why it doesnt work if its findbymodule/1 ? I have that problem in my example..

Comment: @Alexander If the value for parameter is supposed to be taken from route the name of the token in the route definition must match, otherwise Web API will be looking for query parameter (also by name).

Comment: Thank you, this is it. Parameter name must match route template!

Answer (score 1):

My api had too many parameters and I was getting an error. I solved the problem with Route.

```
[Route("addressverification/{id}/{no}/{day}/{month}/{year}")]
public AdressVerificationResult  Get(long? id, long? no ,long? day, long? month, long? year)
        {
        
        return new AdressVerificationResult  
            {
                Aciklama = "19........4 kimlik numaralı kişinin 18.......1 adres numarasında 'YerlesimYeri' adres tipi için geçerli bir yurtiçi adres beyanı mevcuttur.",
                DurumKod = true
            };


         }
```