# Ajax call 404 error but my url is correct (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

Hi I am noob programmer who just got into asp.net mvc and all these js stuff. In my current mvc project I have this weird bug that I just have no idea why it is happening.

I have two almost exact same Ajax calls to a controller for the two different actions in that controller. The GetPages one is successful and the other one is giving me a 404.

//////////////////////////////////////////////The ajax calls/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//get page list

```
GetPages = function (myCategory) {
        var url = config.base + "/api/CMS/GetPagesSorted";

        if (myCategory == null)
            return;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { categoryId: myCategory.Id },
            success: function (data) {
                // Clear pages and add new ones
                self.pageList.removeAll();
                self.pageList(data);
            }
        });
    };
```

//get tab list

```
    GetTabs = function (myPage) {
        var url = config.base + "/api/CMS/GetTabsSorted";

        if (myPage == null)
            return;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { pageId: myPage.Id },
            success: function (data) {
                // Clear tabs and add new ones
                self.tabList.removeAll();
                self.tabList(data);
            }
        });
    };
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////Controller actions being called/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPagesSorted(int categoryId)
    {

        var pages = dbCMS.CMS_Page.Where(x => x.Category.Id == categoryId).Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            OrderId = x.OrderId,
        });
        //sort the page order by OrderId
        pages = pages.OrderBy(x => x.OrderId);

        return Json(pages.ToList());
    }

public IHttpActionResult GetTabsSorted(int pageId)
    {

        var tabs = dbCMS.CMS_Tab.Where(x => x.Page.Id == pageId).Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            OrderId = x.OrderId,
        });
        //sort the page order by OrderId
        tabs = tabs.OrderBy(x => x.OrderId);

        return Json(tabs.ToList());
    }
```

The url for GetPages function is :
    http://localhost:54522/api/CMS/GetPagesSorted

The url for GetTabs function is:
    http://localhost:54522/api/CMS/GetTabsSorted

These are really just copied and pasted functions with only controller action names changed. I really don't think the routing is wrong because one of those calls are getting into the controller and action that I want it to go.

I am really frustrated to find this bug please help! Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: var url =  "/api/CMS/GetPagesSorted"; remove config.base it will automatically be appended in post

Comment: config.base is currently giving me just an empty string. So the url is just /api/CMS/GetPagesSorted. The problem is that /api/CMS/GetPagesSorted works but  /api/CMS/GetTabsSorted is giving me 404

Comment: can you add this data annotation before your actions `[HttpGet]`. If it's ok can you also add your routing configuration

Comment: What happens if you simply navigate in your browser to http://localhost:54522/api/CMS/GetTabsSorted?

Comment: by navigating to the url directly in browser it's giving me this "No action was found on the controller 'CMS' that matches the request." which is just 404

Comment: @katana    I tried to add [HttpGet] to the action but it's not allowed since it's an api controller. Is it possible that it's causing this problem because it's an api controller?

Comment: I figured that both page and tab controller method are similar, including their ajax call method which expected to work at all. I suggest you to check parameter on `routeTemplate`, probably comes from parameter name mismatch in `Routes.MapHttpRoute` definition.

Comment: yah thats correct in an  apicontroller it will only allow one get i think unless you explicitly set the routing of each get method by using this annotation `Route`

Comment: You can set your url like this: `@Url.Action("GetTabsSorted","CMS")`  maybe this is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the error tells us what's going wrong:

`No action was found on the controller 'CMS' that matches the request`

means that Web API routing module didn't found GetTabsSorted with given pageId parameter, or parameter name mismatch occurred.

To resolve possible `GET` method conflicts, define `MapHttpRoute` for each action GetPagesSorted and GetTabsSorted similar to this way:

```
// note parameter differences
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "PagesApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{categoryId}",
    defaults: new { categoryId = RouteParameter.Optional } // change this definition if you want categoryId becomes required
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "TabsApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{pageId}",
    defaults: new { pageId = RouteParameter.Optional } // change this definition if you want pageId becomes required
);
```

Remember that most-specific routes should be defined on top of either default route or less-specific routes.

Reference: [WebAPI No action was found on the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481592/webapi-no-action-was-found-on-the-controller)